# How to notify users peridocally from an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall, facebook-timeline

So there's an app, let's say it's an app that is capable of delivering relevant news based on the user's choice done the first time he runs the app. Is there a way to post the news to the user's wall without having the user to be online and ideally as the app?

So on his/hers timeline it would look like this (edited image, not a real post from some app, it's just so you get what I mean):

[image: Facebook wall post]

When I use `$facebook->api('/me', 'post')`, it just creates a post as the user, which is not what I want and does not allow me to post when the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [server side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) to get a long lived access token (60 days) which you can then use until the token times out. Then you'll need to have the user reengage with your app to get a new token.

You can get the same thing by using the [client side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) and then [extending the token](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) on the server side.

Another options which should work for you is to get an app access token (which does not expire) and ask the user for the `publish_stream` permission, then:

> App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on
>   behalf of a user who has granted a publishing permission to your
>   application.

Comment: The problem is, that I don't want to post on behalf of the user but rather as the app itself

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't post on a user wall as the app itself, on as a user.